# How do I delete a vote (e.g.rate module)?

Tags: rating

Is there a module with a functionality to delete votes using the voting api? If not, how do I implement a button that erases *all* votes? Or is it easier if I just empty the MYSQL table?

Comment: You should look at [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) working together with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Voting Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/voting_rules). You should create a rules component to delete a vote on a node (or whatever) and then integrate it with View Bulk Operations.

Comment: @J.Reynolds, that doesn't seem to work. Voting Rules gives conditions and events for rules, but it doesn't give any actions, it seems.

Comment: Writing custom plugins for Rules are some of the easiest Drupal programming to do. There is a patch [Allow casting new votes with Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1444030). You can expand on that if you need to. You should create an action to delete a vote, it must pass a parameter of a vote, and then take action by doing this: votingapi_delete_votes(array($vote));

Comment: @J.Reynolds Thanks, I'll try to do that. How do I construct a `$vote`, though, if I only know the entity id of the object that has been voted on?

Comment: Open up the votingapi.module file and look at the documented functions, especially votingapi_add_votes, votingapi_add_results, votingapi_delete_votes, votingapi_select_votes etc. For hooks look in votingapi.api.php

Answer (score 1):

The voting api defines some drush commands:

```
drush generate-votes <entity_type> <vote_type>
drush votingapi-recalculate <entity_type>
drush votingapi-flush <entity_type>
```

if you don't use drush, you can run the code from the function that the module uses on devel php or similar

```
<?php
$entity_type = "name_of_the_entity";
$cache = db_delete('votingapi_cache');
$votes = db_delete('votingapi_vote');

if (!empty($entity_type)) {
  $cache->condition('entity_type', $entity_type);
  $votes->condition('entity_type', $entity_type);
}
if (!empty($entity_id)) {
  $cache->condition('entity_id', $entity_id);
  $votes->condition('entity_id', $entity_id);
}

$cache->execute();
$votes->execute();
```